# C++ text document

Tags: c++, io, fstream

Its probably an easy answer and i hope its easy to understand my question.
I have a text document that has a lot of lines and several paragraphs

Is there a way to merge all lines into one single line without doing it manually?
The reason i am asking this its because lets say I am searching for a specific word in a  document that only has one paragraph.(let say the paragraph has 10 lines) If that word its in that one paragraph its suppose to  return paragraph1 accepted. But what my program its doing something weird instead its giving me an output like this:

```
paragraph1:accepted
paragraph2:accepted
paragraph3:accepted
paragraph4:accepted
paragraph5:accepted
paragraph6:accepted
paragraph7:accepted
paragraph8:accepted
paragraph9:accepted
paragraph10:accepted
```

This is the code that reads my document

```
    void processParagraph(std::string &paragraph, size_t paragraphNumber)
   {

    ifstream input;
    input.open("data.txt"); //opens the text file with the documents

    if (input.fail()) //if the file doesn't open
     {
      cout << "file not found" << endl;
      return;
     }

    if (isMyWordThere(paragraph)) //if the word im looking its there 
     cout << "paragraph " << paragraphNumber << ": accepted" << endl;
     else // if the word its not there 
      cout << "paragraph " << paragraphNumber << ": not accepted" << endl;
      paragraph.clear(); // reset the paragraph to handle the next one.


    std::string line;
    std::string paragraph;
    size_t paragraphNumber = 0;
    while ( getline(input, line) ) // read a LINE
     {
      if ( !line.empty() ) // paragraph not finished
       {
        paragraph.append("\n").append(line);
       }
     else // paragraph finished, because we found an empty line
      {
        ++paragraphNumber;
        processParagraph(paragraph, paragraphNumber);
      }
     }
     if ( !paragraph.empty() )
      {
       processParagraph(paragraph, paragraphNumber);
      }
   }
```

Its there a way to merge all lines into one, or a way that i can change my code so it doesnt count lines?

The input file looks like this:(im looking for the word "hello")

```
hello world
hello everyone
hello All
```

The output should look like this

```
paragraph 1: accepted
```

but what im getting is

```
paragraph 1: accepted
paragraph 2: accepted
paragraph 3: accepted
```

Comment: You don't think there might be a problem with the `isMyWordThere` function?

Comment: Also remember that `std::getline` reads one line at a time, not "paragraphs".

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the function because it does find the word. Ok so what im basically doing its combining like 10 text files into one textfile with 10 paragraphs. and displaying which paragraph has the word. Is there a way to modify my code without merging those documents into one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're processing *lines* not *paragraphs*.

This will do it:

```
void processParagraph(std::string &paragraph, size_t paragraphNumber)
{
    if (isMyWordThere(paragraph)) //if the word im looking its there 
        std::cout << "paragraph " << paragraphNumber << ": accepted" << std::endl;
    else // if the word its not there 
        std::cout << "paragraph " << paragraphNumber << ": not accepted" << std::endl;
    paragraph.clear(); // reset the paragraph to handle the next one.
}

void processFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream input;
    input.open(filename.c_str()); // open file
    std::string line;
    std::string paragraph;
    size_t paragraphNumber = 0;
    while ( getline(input, line) ) // read a LINE
    {
       if ( !line.empty() ) // paragraph not finished
       {
           paragraph.append("\n").append(line);
       }
       else // paragraph finished, because we found an empty line
       {
           ++paragraphNumber;
           processParagraph(paragraph, paragraphNumber);
       }
    }
    if ( !paragraph.empty() )
    {
        processParagraph(paragraph, paragraphNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not helping. **Edit your question** and add a valid input file and the *expected* output. We have to see the different lines!

Comment: Im trying to. how do you add line breaks to comments?

Comment: Ok, if you use my code with exactly that file content, it's going to work. If it's still wrong, your `isMyWordHere` is wrong.

Comment: ok so the code is giving me an error declaration of std:: string paragraph shadows a parameter. I edited my question so that it includes the ifstream input.

Comment: ok i didnt notice, everything was all in one function.. Is it possible to do all that code in one function. Or how do you seperate it with 2 functions?

Comment: You have weird names for functions and I frankly don't know why you are doing it that way. I'll update my answer shortly to give you more information.

Comment: nvm, i think i probably just confused, you thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to split this functionality out into a separate function, that can either take a filename or an open file stream. Then call this function once for each file.